# Visual Studio MSVRC110.dll Error (Error 0x80070641)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I can not reinstall visual studio, this uninstall steamed from a licensing problem, and have no way currently of effectively.

> [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:04]: Application requested retry of package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, encountered error: 0x80070641. Retrying...
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:07]: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{CF2BEA3C-26EA-32F8-AA9B-331F7E34BA97}v11.0.61030\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:08]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:08]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:08]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:08]: Application requested retry of package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, encountered error: 0x80070641. Retrying...
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:11]: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{CF2BEA3C-26EA-32F8-AA9B-331F7E34BA97}v11.0.61030\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:11]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:11]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:11]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:11]: Application requested retry of package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, encountered error: 0x80070641. Retrying...
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{CF2BEA3C-26EA-32F8-AA9B-331F7E34BA97}v11.0.61030\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.
>   [673C:6638][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x80070641, restart: None
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Error 0x80070641: Failed to execute MSI package.
>   [64C8:6634][2015-04-30T03:36:14]: Apply complete, result: 0x80070641, restart: None, bad requested restart:  No

Comment: Your machine is pretty broken, the installer service cannot be started.  Disable anti-malware first.  Try starting it by hand with Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > Windows Installer > Start.  Look for errors in the event log.

Comment: @HansPassant I have gone through most steps basic logical and have repaired everything with the computer down to registry errors and done defrags, I do understand that it is unreasonable to believe this is the issue, and my PC is running the best it even has I just can't install visual studio and do my class c++ assignment. The only antivirus software I use is microsoft security, as a base firewall protection in conjunction with Malware Fighter 3 for actual security, but I will try that again with everything down.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that and about a million other things since posting here I am pretty sure this was caused by a covert virus, reader_sl.exe?. I think at this point I just need to fix this one error code, but can't find any good documentation. Do you know what Error 0x80070643 is or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Windows Essentials Gave me this:      Error 0x80070643 ->wllogin_amd64?? I am on an intel based system with no amd parts at all                                                   Dammit... http://ask-leo.com/i_have_multiple_winlogonexe_files_on_my_machine_and_ones_taking_up_a_lot_of_memory_what_do_i_do.html

Comment: @user2454745 "AMD64" is the name for 64-bit. It's an AMD developed extension to x86 commands, which ultimately won popularity over Intel's i64. AMD64 was subsequently adopted by Intel, and prior to ARM support was the only 64-bit command set that Windows supported.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've been able to reach this error is to try to uninstall in safe mode.

Uninstallations of Visual Studio *or the redistributables* done in safe mode will fail with the error:

> Error 0x80070641: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.